# Android - Part of the scroll should not hide after reaching the top of the scrollview

Tags: android

I have a scroll view in which it has an image at the beginning of the scroll and then a text field and finally a list of images. What I want is that when i scroll the view the image section should get scrolled but when it reaches the text field, the text field should not get scrolled up rather it should stay like its the header and the list below it should still get scrolled.

Please suggest me a way to accomplish this design.

Comment: check this out https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyScrollViewItems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is, the image should be scrolled first and when it reaches to textfield the header should be stick at that place.

Refer this
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/266.

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: Thanks @MashukKhan... I think this will work... This is what i wanted..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of taking the whole layout in scroll, take first an image, then the header textview and then take listview, and in different layout file for listview row, take imageview and display the list.